# Get the next element of an array

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have such an array:

```
{"1":"https:\/\/proxy1...","2":"https:\/\/proxy2...","3":"https:\/\/proxy2...","7":"https:\/\/proxy2...", "10":"https:\/\/proxy2..."}
```

Еhere is a variable that contains the element id. For example:
randElem = 3

I need to get the next element of an array. If the element ids are consecutively 1,2,3,4,5, there is no problem. Was it like this:

```
randElem = 3
data = json.load(open('proxies.json'))
count = len(data)

if randElem > count:
    print(data[str(1)])
elif randElem == count:
    print(data[str(randElem)])
else:
    randElem = randElem+1
    print(data[str(randElem)])
```

But, if the array is like above, it doesn't work.
And also if randElem = the last element in the array. Need to get the first element

How can I do it?

Comment: What should the output be for the data above when `randElem = 4`?

Comment: It cannot exist if the proxy with this id is not in the array above

Comment: That's not an array (nor a list), it's a dictionary. You access dictionaries by key, and if you want to access all the elements in order, you can just loop over the `.keys()` and access the elements as usual. If you need the 'next' key after some known key, you can find the key in `.keys()` and get the next one from that.

Comment: But `3` also isn't in there. Do you mean `"3"`?

Comment: @Grismar *"That's not an array"* - From Python's official [glossary](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-dictionary): *"dictionary: An associative array"*.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because A) were it to be about lists it would be a duplicate and B) the OP is referencing JSON with is identical to a dict, and therefore not a list.

Comment: @KellyBundy that remark is entirely unhelpful and disingenuous, and you know it.

Comment: @Grismar I disagree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first create a sorted list of the keys from the dict and use that to find the next key.

```py
ids = sorted(map(int, data))
randElem = min(randElem, ids[-1])
idx = ids.index(randElem) # assuming the key exists
print(data[str(ids[(idx + 1) % len(ids)])])
```

Answer (score 0):

An iterator way:

```
it = iter(data)
randElem in it
print(next(it, next(iter(data))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM7YoKPr/vygxL8U1JzVXwVZByViJKyWxJBHIrFYyVLJSyigpKSi2itGP0S8oyq@oNNTT01PSUTLClDGCyBjjlDHHJaOgZGiAQ66WiyuzBOiWzJLUIg2QuzS54I7NzAMKcxUUZeaVaOSlVpRoZJboKEAZMNVA8P8/AA)

Comment: This seems to suppose that the keys are sorted.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel No, they're asking for "next element", and that's exactly what I'm doing. They're not asking for "next-larger element" (although their example makes it look like that's the same in their data).

Comment: @KarlKnechtel And they also say "last" and "first", not "largest" and "smallest".